# Maintain indentation from previous row in vim

Tags: vim, vi, auto-indent

What is the name of the option which keeps the indentation  when moving to a new row.

**Example**

```
Subject
    This is indented and now i press enter
    I would like indentation to happen automatically

Subject
    This is indented and now i press enter
I currently start here here and indent manually
```

Comment: try `set ai` , see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual (`:help indent.txt`):

> `autoindent` uses the indent from the previous line

...so:

```
:set autoindent
```

If this does not work for you try starting Vim without plugins
and skipping `.vimrc` initializations:

```
vim -u NONE -N
```

Comment: The plug-ins and .vimrc were interfering.